# How to Create Function Search Jquery Easy UI in controller Codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I Try tutorial from http://www.jeasyui.com/tutorial/datagrid/datagrid24.php

I create this function in mycontroller..

```
function doSearch(){
$('#tt').datagrid('load',{
itemid: $('#itemid').val(),
productid: $('#productid').val()
});
}
```

I get error message like this..

Parse error: parse error, expecting `T_VARIABLE' or`'$'' in C:\xampp\htdocs\ci_jquery\application\controllers\crud.php on line 55

I dont know, how to create that function in controller codeigniter.
Thanks For The Reply..

Comment: Can you please update your question with the contents of the C:\xampp\htdocs\ci_jquery\application\controllers\crud.php file? That's where the problem is.

Comment: the error on line 55 in $('#tt').datagrid('load',{

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that the code which you've posted is not PHP code, it's Javascript code (more specifically, it belongs to the jQuery framework). It does **not** need to live in a controller, but instead should be added to the view, where your HTML content is.

You first need to load a view file, and then add the code above into it.

```
$this->load->view('myview');
```

You would then have to add the Javascript code which you've posted into your view file (in the example I've provided, that would be in *application/views/myview.php*. Make sure to also include the jQuery library in your template!

You can read more on views here: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/views.html

Comment: thanks petre.. I should create the function in view. Thanks for help.. :)